# Does EJB server supports error tracking after Deployment?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.1, java-server

I'm new in EJB. Recently I'm researching about software reliability,especially in Enterprise application. I'm wondering if EJB application server supports error tracking after the deployment. 

For example, When you deploy your EJB application in real world, sometime, even with very tiny probability, your system can still make mistake because of Services (e.g in transaction, concurrency,... vertical,horizontal services or business EJBs in general that affect system performance). In that case, the whole system may be stopped or not.
My question is that Does EJB application server support any error tracking API to recognize and record all information about these error ?


All mistakes about logic programming are not concerned.


Thank you and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EJB specification requires the EJB container to log all system exceptions.  For most bean types, it also requires the EJB container to discard the bean instance when a system exception is thrown and to use other instances to service future requests.

Comment: Are system & JVM exceptions logged automatically or we have to handle by ourselves ? Can you explain this problem more clearly? Thank so much.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say the spec requires the EJB container to do those things.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: Oh, I see. is these log stored somewhere and can we get these information from server ?

Comment: Presumably yes. The exact location of the logs is product-specific.  For WebSphere Application Server (the one I'm most familiar with), the errors go to PROFILE_HOME/logs/SERVER/SystemOut.log (or server/SERVER/messages.log on Liberty profile) by default.